# Android builder doesnot show api 19 in the list, even after downloading the sdk 4.4

Tags: android

I am only getting a list of API upto 18. I have however downloaded the latest sdk ( 4.4 ) for api 19, but still i cannot see it in the list.

Edit: I am using Android Builder ( not eclipse )

Comment: did you update your ADT?

Comment: using android builder. I cannot see ADT in there!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also update the Android Developer Tools (ADT) plugin. If you're using Eclipse, go to `Help > Check for Updates` to get the latest version.